# Trouble installing ADT plugin in eclipse (for developing android apps)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, plugins, adt

I already had Eclipse (kepler) installed to create java programs.
Now I wanted to develop android apps, so I wanted to install the ADT plugin for Eclipse.
I read the following:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download

I did those steps exactly.
Then, on that same page, I read this paragraph:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Configure

But I don't understand what I have to do.
When Eclipse restarts, I get a popup diolog which asks me to choose a path which has to lead to a folder. I can't find any folder. I don't see anything changed in my file system.
I don't see any folder which looks like Android SDK. I think I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You need the SDK as well. You can find it here:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools

When you install it you have to insert the path of your SDK in the Eclipse popup dialog

I encourage you to update the SDK on your first launch through SDK manager